# 450nm peak absorption

Tags: optics, visible-light, spectroscopy, absorption, raman-spectroscopy

I am looking for an oxide compound (metal oxide, or similar preferably inorganic) which shows light peak absorption at 450 nm. I have troubles in finding the right compound, as most of the oxides have peak absorption in the UV region at around 350 nm
The oxide should be preferably in white color or similar.
Is there a compound with these properties?
Is there a reason if most readibly available compounds have peak absorption in the UV region?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is really no physics in your question: it is just “tell me the answer.”

Comment: There are a variety of iron oxides, some of which are red or reddish, e.g., jeweler’s red rouge. Good luck!

Comment: @MattHanson What do you mean there is no physics? I am looking for a compound with certain optical properties. Of course there is. If you have nothing positive to add, better to abstain comments

Comment: So you want something white that absorbs green light? Do you see a contradiction there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cerium doped scintillation crystals made from gadolinium aluminum gallium garnet, see https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-77451-x.

In metal oxides, the valence band is primarily composed of oxygen 2p orbitals, while the conduction band is mainly made up of metal cation d or s orbitals. The large energy difference between these orbitals results in a wide band gap and absorption below 400 nm.

Metals whose d or s orbitals (forming the conduction band) are closer in energy to the oxygen 2p orbitals can result in a narrower band gap. Transition metals are often good candidates due to their d orbital energies.

Also, doping and alloying can reduce the gap. In the example above, you get all of it. Purity is your enemy.

Comment: I was hoping to find some more accessible compound. TiO2 has absorbance peak between 350 and 400 nm. Maybe I could find a titanium alloy oxide which gets closer to the target?